# Get parent node from child and rename it

Tags: xslt

I have the input bellow and I wrote some xslt that gives me an office with a specific ID but since I get the parent node I also get the tag `<e>`. My problem is that I don't want to have that `<e>` tag.

```
 <response>
   <offices>
     <e>
      <id>33701</id>
      <name>aa</name>
     </e>
      .....<e></e>

   </offices>
 </response>

  <xsl:template match="*:response/offices">
        <econ:GetOfficesResponse>
            <Office>
                <xsl:for-each select="e/id">
                    <xsl:if test="text() = $office_id">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="parent::node()"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Office>
        </econ:GetOfficesResponse>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The response that I get:

```
<econ:GetOfficesResponse>
   <Office>
      <e>
        <id>33701</id>
        <name>...</name>
  </e>
 </Office>
```

The response that I want:

```
<econ:GetOfficesResponse>
   <Office>
        <id>33701</id>
        <name>...</name>
 </Office>
```

Can someone please help me with this? I/m using xslt 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like instead of your `xsl:for-each` you simply want a single `<xsl:copy-of select="e[id = $office_id]/*"/>`

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

`<xsl:template match="*:response/offices">
    <econ:GetOfficesResponse>
        <Office>
            <xsl:for-each select="e/id">
                <xsl:if test="text() = $office_id">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="parent::node()/child::node()"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Office>
    </econ:GetOfficesResponse>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: Thank you, that works as well. But I think that it may save me some computing time to skip over the for loop.